# Parsing KQL Json and using it to join another table

Tags: kql, windows-defender

I am trying to query in Defender Advanced hunting

Basically where I am having an issue is parsing the json for LoggedOnUsers and joining certain data there which is the Sid with IdentityInfo's CloudSid

For this one I am getting the error

> Semantic error Error message Ensure that expression: LoggedOnUsers.Sid
> is indeed a simple name How to resolve Fix semantic errors in your
> query

```html
DeviceTvmSoftwareInventory
| where SoftwareName contains "softwarename"
| distinct DeviceId, SoftwareName
| join kind=inner (
    DeviceInfo 
    | mv-expand parsejson(LoggedOnUsers)
    | extend LoggedOnUsers_Sid = tostring(toscalar(LoggedOnUsers.Sid))
    | project DeviceId, LoggedOnUsers_Sid
    )
    on DeviceId
| join kind=inner (
    IdentityInfo
    )
    on $left.LoggedOnUsers_Sid == $right.CloudSid
| project DeviceId, SoftwareName, AccountUpn
```